# Didn't find class on DexPathList

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I have a probelm with my app. Im working on Android Studio 0.8.4

and I get this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   com.twittstr.TwittstrApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class "com.twittstr.TwittstrApplication" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.twittstr-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.twittstr-1,
>   /system/lib]]
>               at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.twittstr.TwittstrApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.twittstr-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.twittstr-1,
>   /system/lib]]
>               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
>               at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I know that there are already similar questions here on stackoverflow. However, the suggested answer was to make a clean in eclipse or someone has had the wrong package name in the manifest. I could not find one of these problems for my app.

My Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.twittstr">


  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="20" />


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

  <application android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.Twittstr"
      android:name="com.twittstr.TwittstrApplication"
      >

    <activity android:name="com.twittstr.login.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Twittstr.Login"
        >

      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>

    </activity>

  </application>

</manifest>
```

I have included other projects from other locations (not in the gradle project path. 
My settings.gradle:

> include ':app'
>
> project(':dagger').projectDir = new File('~/android/dagger')

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 20
  buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.twittstr"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      runProguard false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'LICENSE'
    exclude 'NOTICE'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 // wearApp project(':wear')
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'

  // Annotation Processing
  compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
  apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'


  compile project (':dagger')


  // ActionItem
  compile 'com.tundem.actionitembadge:library:1.1.0@aar'
  compile 'com.balysv:material-menu:1.0.0'


  // compile 'com.github.japgolly.android:svg-android:2.0.6'


  // Twitter
  compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
}
```

The dependecies can be resloved correctly.

Probably its a Android Studio problem. More likely is that I have a very dumb error in the manifest, but I cant see it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Obvious question: do you have a `com.twittstr.TwittstrApplication` class and does it extend `Application`?

Comment: yes and yes :) If I remove the android:name attribute from xml application tag then I will get the same error with The LoginActivity ... `Didn't find class "com.twittstr.login.LoginActivity" on path`. The classes are in the correct packages hierarchy. Android Studio autocompletes the package in the manifest file

Comment: Would you also post your build.gradle?

Comment: I have added the build.gradle file

Comment: Man, that's puzzling... You could try the following: close Android Studio, delete .idea folder (contains IDE files), then reimport (not re-open) your project.
EDIT: see if your classes are excluded in .idea/compiler.xml

Answer (score 0):

First: 
In your class `TwittstrApplication`, add this: `@EApplication`.

Then in your manifest, change:

```
android:name="com.twittstr.TwittstrApplication"
```

to

```
android:name="com.twittstr.TwittstrApplication_"
```

Clean & build. It worked for me.